# Trying to center a bunch of col-md-10 divs but not centering

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center a bunch of articles which are within a container. I am currently using the helper class `center-block` with the css `float: none;` on the container but it does not center it. I have tried to put `center-block` within the actual `col-md-10` article containers but that caused for a triangle-like effect.

How can I center the article divs and what have I been doing wrong?

```
<template>
  <div class="articles">
    <h1 v-text="title"></h1>
    <div v-if="Object.keys(articles).length !== 0" class="center-block">
      <div v-for="article in articles" class="col-md-10 article-border">
        <h1 v-text="article.title"></h1>
        <img :src="article.image" class="pull-left img-responsive margin10 thumb img-thumbnail">
        <p v-text="article.content">
        </p>
        <a class="btn btn-success pull-right marginBottom10" :href="article.url">Continue Reading..</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>No Articles Found!</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

...

```
.center-block {
    float: none;
}
```

Output currently:

[image]

Output desired:

[image]

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rx9ohzg3/1/

Comment: Share you code/demo ?

Comment: Try with the Flexbox on the same div: `display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center;`

Comment: The only other code is the <script> which involves objects of articles (i.e. article.title would return the article title like in the HTML). It's a .vue file (I have provided the <template> and CSS, only remainder is <script>) and I'm not exactly sure yet how to translate that in to a jsfiddle

Comment: @VXp How about this? https://jsfiddle.net/rx9ohzg3/1/

Answer (score 0):

To do it with the means which Bootstrap provides, use the corresponding `offset` class: Add the class `offset-md-1` to the element which has `col-md-10` to move it to right by one column, thereby centering it. (12 columns overall width minus 10 for your DIV = 2, divided by 2 for left and right = 1 column which should remain empty at the left side)

You can see it in this codepen which contains the same code as your fiddle with (almost) only that offset class added:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaKege

Note: I also replaced your `pull-right` class for the button with the `float-right` class since  `pull-right` was removed in Bootstrap 4

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I updated my bootstrap and modified as shown however one issue - my buttons break when I use the offset.

Comment: did you read the last line of my answer (replacing `pull-right` with `float-right`)?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant when I said I modified as shown. I changed the `pull`'s to `float`'s

Comment: And you are using Bootstrap 4? (As you can see in my codepen, it works in bootstrap 4)

Comment: Yes I am using 4.0.0-beta.2

Comment: For reference this is how it looks if I use the flex solution in the comments: http://i.imgur.com/cLSEEsr.png